# On ubuntu server: run Chrome as a different user (not root) not working

Tags: linux, google-chrome, bash, root, ubuntu-server

*[I'm a newbie, so tx for the patience]*

I tried to run chrome on an ubunto server and got this:
`root@stender:/opt/google/chrome# ./chrome.....ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported`

I tried to add a user with:
`useradd chrome3`

Got no reply (might as well worked)

Then I tried: 
`gksu -u chrome3 google-chrome`

But I got this error:

`-bash: gksu: command not found`

Please help!!!

Comment: Question... <i>gksu: command not found</i>. Did you install `gksu`? You should find it in `/usr/bin/gksu`. If there you call directly with `/usr/bin/gksu -u chrome3 ...`  where `...` means the path to your program (google-chrome in this case). You can `locate gksu` if it is not in `/usr/bin` directory. With `apt-get install gksu` you should be able to install gksu if not present on your system.

Comment: It's possible to do in many different ways, from simple to difficult ones. Just to give you an idea (https://calum.org/posts/running-firefox-as-another-user-using-sudo), but warning there are several serious security issues doing as the link above, fixable but serious...Please [edit] you question adding what do you mean with a <i>different user</i>: if you want that the cache, the access rights, the configuration files belong to a separate linux user, of you just want a different profile (history/settings/bookmarks) for "physical" users or moods (work / free time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to run Chrome as root, add the appropriate flag as in `./chrome --no-sandbox`. As the name implies, this will run Chrome with reduced security.

`useradd` usually requires flags to create the home folder and set the shell to something other than the POSIX `sh` shell, so the command should have been `useradd -m -s /bin/bash chrome3`. Since the user account has already been created, you can fix the shell by running `chsh -s /bin/bash chrome3` and create a home folder for chrome3 with `usermod -m --home /home/chrome3` as root.

If you don't have `gksu`, you can install it via `apt-get install gksu` as an elevated user.